# How to force Visual Studio to execute .exe instead of .dll?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

My solution has 2 projects, both of them are `.dll`s. These are copied over for my `.exe` to work. After clicking `F5` on my project, I want an `.exe` to run. Instead, what I get is:

[image]

Even if in `Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command`, my command is correct...

[image]

I'm sure it's working for both configurations: release and debug. Projects are building fine, copying to correct directory fine as well. Are there any other properties that I missed?

Comment: If you have 2 projects then you have 50% odds for having it wrong.  99.9% when it turns into an SO question.  Right-click the project whose name is not in **bold** type and select "Set as Startup Project".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) I agree with Hans Passant's suggestion. Please make sure that you really setup your .exe project as the start up project in your solution explorer window.

(2) Please check that which it really has .exe file in your project output folder. Maybe you set the wrong "Configuration Type" in your start up project.

[image]

Comment: @K. Kaj, If possible, please share the latest information in your side.